# how to select records depending on outcome of 2 queries

Tags: sql

I have a tables

**Table a** `( id,name, start_date)`

**Table b** `(id(FK to Table a), start_date)`

Here is my problem statement:

1. if id exists in Table b, then select the value of start_date from table b else select the default start_date from table a

I can get the logic working by having 2 seperate queries , my challenge is to achieve it in single query?
Is is possible to achieve in single query?

Comment: Is is possible to achieve in single query?: Yes.  The simplest approach seems to involve an OUTER JOIN (LEFT) and the coalese function, or possibly a case statement.  Other soltions may work as well, however they are RDBMS dependant, so what RDBMS is this and what version? (MySQL, SQL Sever(2013)?, Oracle(11i)?, DB2)  coalesce simply says take the first non-null value encountered in a near endless series of options provided.  When used with a Left join that will produce a Null value if it doesn't exist... seems to fit your attempt. @AndreiHirsu appears to have it defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    a.ID
   , COALESCE(b.start_date,a.start_date)
FROM
   TableA a
LEFT JOIN
   TableB b
ON a.id = b.Id
```

Comment: Thanks that helped. Sorry I not a regular SQL programmer hence did not provide much information.I already had the solution with 2 queries in place. Just wanted to optimize it further.